# Udev rule for disabling usb serial driver

Tags: linux, usb, udev, tty

I have an ANT+ USB dongle, and some software I wrote, which uses libusb to communicate with the device.

On recent linux distributions (like Ubuntu 18.04) when I plug in the dongle, in my dmesg I see the following:

`#dmesg output
[55632.489138] usb 1-10: USB disconnect, device number 26
[55634.300338] usb 1-10: new full-speed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
[55634.452005] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=0fcf, idProduct=1008
[55634.452012] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[55634.452016] usb 1-10: Product: Movestick mini
[55634.452020] usb 1-10: Manufacturer: Suunto
[55634.452024] usb 1-10: SerialNumber: 1323802187
[55634.454188] usb_serial_simple 1-10:1.0: suunto converter detected
[55634.454494] usb 1-10: suunto converter now attached to ttyUSB0`

It is attaching a serial driver, and when it does this, I can't seem to access the USB device directly with libusb.
If I unbind the serial driver with:

`echo -n "1-10:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb_serial_simple/unbind`

it works just fine.

What I would like to do, is not have to do this manually every time. Is there a way I can disable the loading of `usb_simple_serial` for that dongle?

I found some examples of writing udev rules to explicitly load the serial driver (older linux distros would not automatically load it), but I need the exact opposite.

For example, on older distros, they would do this, to load the serial driver:

`echo "options usbserial vendor=0x0fcf product=0x1008" > /etc/modprobe.d/ant-usb2.conf`

And

`echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="tty" ACTION=="add" ATTRS{idProduct}=="1008" ATTRS{idVendor}=="0fcf" SYMLINK+="ttyANT"' > /etc/udev/rules/ant.rule`

Can I make a udev rule to do the exact opposite, and NOT load the driver?
Also I would need the device to be accessible by all users, and not just root. How could I make that happen via the udev rule?